# Successfully installed pyg but couldn't import

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-geometric

I successfully installed the pyg package and other four related packages as pic shows: [pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kR0Q8.png)

however, when I tried to import it in my python code, it doesn't work:
[pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTE5b.png)

Does anyone know why? For more information, I use pip to install these packages, and I can see pyg package when I use `pip list`, but I couldn't find it when I use `conda list`

Comment: Make sure you installed the packages on which python version, if you have multiple versions.

Comment: Try to install it by conda instead on pip.